# Angular2 Routing with base selector as Component in index.html

Tags: javascript, angular

I have define 2 Routes LoginComponent and DashboardComponent and their is one main component which is the base component appComponent (which i have not used)

What I want is:

1. First Load the LoginComponent and then I Login Successfully then I want to Load the DashboardComponent.

What I have done is:

1. I have make the base component to the loginComponent as a selector in index.html page and when I successfully login the the LoginComponent View not Removed and Replace to Dashboard Page.

Here is my Code:

**Routes**:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login',pathMatch:'full' },
    { path: '**', component: NotFound404Component }
];
```

Used this for login function:

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
```

Any help would appriciated.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: You need to use the app component selector in index.html, not the login selector. The app component then needs a router outlet directive. Its the router outlet that replaces the pages for you.

Comment: @DeborahK yes u were write but how router-outlet directive know to pick the login selector now ??  Is their is flow that we have have write in the app.module.ts file while defining the components Ex :- After this (appComponent ) component this component (LoginComponent) will come only . Is that We Can Say FLOW MATTERS in declarations Array in metadata of NgModule in app.module.ts file ???

Comment: Your default route in your route configuration should route the user to the login route. I have a course on routing if you are interested in learning more: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update/table-of-contents